# Find if a string contains a name like 'John' or a general word

Tags: c++, string

I want to find all the person names like John etc. embedded in a piece of english text. What is the best way to do this in C++?

Comment: Do you have a list of names? How many names? What size is your piece of text?

Comment: I do not have a list of names and the size of the piece of user-uploaded text is variable.

Comment: The problem with especially English text is that you can get names from pretty much any country. But a case like "Ban Ki-moon" will be a problem in any language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a toolkit - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_processing_toolkits. There are several in C or C++ and these will have tools for Proper names. The names will be identified by lookup, by context and by other NLP heuristics. This may need to be combined with a lookup service if you have a special requirement.

An example:

```
John fed his dog
```

A good NLP toolkit will know the name John and also parse "his" as a personal possessive pronoun , so identifying John as not only a noun, but a proper noun.

Suggest you try out some of the tools - I think several of them will have online demos.

If you also need to identify the people behind the names (e.g. author disambiguation) this is a hard task - many people are working on it.

Comment: Thank you for your post. I am trying to use AlchemyAPI now.